# Zebra Barcode Scanner SDK : Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, barcode-scanner

Are there any **examples/GitHub projects/documents** available online to integrate Zebra Barcode Scanning SDK into Xamarin Forms App for both iOS and Android ?

Moreover, Can we install our own Xamarin Forms App on Zebra Rugged Barcode Scanners ? If so what are the device types ?

Comment: do Zebra devices run Android?  Can third party apps be installed?  If so, then the answer to your 2nd question is "yes"

Comment: @Jason: Thanks. So do we need to include Zebra SDK on our App to make it work ?? Or is it just plug and Play ??

Comment: I have no idea.  You need to read the docs.  In general most devices with built in scanners just relay their input via the keyboard, so the app does not need to use the SDK for basic scanning.  It really depends on what specifically you need to accomplish.

Comment: @Jason : Thank you. So will Zebra Scanners work on iOS too ??

Comment: http://www.zebra.com

Answer (score 0):

The best resource for a Xamarin Forms app that demonstrates barcode scanning on a Zebra device is https://github.com/Zebra/Inventory and you can find links to the associated blog post in the README.  That sample app uses DataWedge and not the scanning SDK which is the recommended approach for new applications.  The app itself will work on iOS but will only capture barcodes on Zebra Android devices - if you also want it to capture barcodes on iOS or consumer Android devices then you will need to add that separately.

Comment: I am acutally looking for SDK to integrate with my own app so that users can but Zebra scanners for using

Comment: This is for Android devices yes?  The SDK is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Symbol.XamarinEMDK/ and a sample which does not use Xamarin Forms is https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/6-0/samples/barcode/.  I am not aware of any sample that uses Forms other than the one I posted above.